# HTML Title From json - SEO Friendly Way?

Tags: javascript, seo

Changing the page title using jQuery, changes the title on the load of the page - but is there a SEO friendly way to do this?

My data is coming from json and I am handling it in jQuery.

```
document.title = 'test';
```

Comment: As far as I know that is SEO unfreindly. Bots will not execute JS, so the title is not set. If you have such dynamic pages you have to do workarounds with phantom.js or something to generate static contents for Bots ...

Comment: Thanks, so it would just be easier for me to write this in php I guess if there is no easy work around?

Comment: Yes, generating pages with php and delivering static content is the better way in this case I think ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bots will only see the static title of the page as it is served by the webserver. Nothing you do in JavaScript will have any effect on that data. Furthermore, your approach is unfriendly to any browser with no JavaScript, making it wholly inaccessible.

You should control your title on the server; perhaps with a PHP script?!

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it at least confirms my thoughts

Comment: @eisbehr: It's bad form to impose your own personally chosen aesthetic on answers two minutes after they're posted.

Comment: @eisbehr: _In your opinion_.